# How to access element in Iterable Tuple (Scala)

Tags: scala, filter, tuples, rdd

I am creating an application using **Scala**, and I am struggling to understand some things.

My first question is about **Iterable tuples**:

What is the difference bettween **Iterable tuples** and **Normal tuples**? When and how to use them?

Secondly and more specific *about my application*:

I have an RDD which has this form:

`(Double, Double), Iterable[(String, String)]`

The **1st** tuple is the **key**, and the **2nd** contains some **values**.

Now let's say that I want to perform a .filter() method on my RDD, using the 1st element from the 2nd Tuple. To do that I have written the code shown bellow:

```
val filteredRDD = oldRDD.filter{ case ((key,value)) => value.filter(x => x._1 == "some_string") }
```

- **key** : is refering to the 1st tuple: (Double, Double)
- **value** : is refering to the 2nd tuple: Iterable[(String, String)]

When I run this line of code I get this error:

> error: type mismatch;  found   : Iterable[(String,
>   String)]  required: Boolean

whereas when I am trying to use filter on the **1st tuple** as shown bellow:

```
val filteredRDD = oldRDD.filter{ case ((key,value)) => key._1 == 5.4 }
```

everything is working fine!

So what is the **proper way** to use the **filter() method** base on the **1st element** of the **2nd tuple** which is **Iterable**?

Thank you so much on behalf, and please excuse me if this sounds too dumb. I am new to this coding language.

Comment: Your rdd contains a tuple and an iterable of tuple ?

Comment: You need to first select the first element

Comment: **Iterable** means it is a collection of **Tuples**, meaning there are many. Second, the `filter` on **RDD** expects a **Function** that receives an element of the collection and returns a **Boolean**, which determines which elements should remain and which don't in the returned collection. And then you are calling another `filter` inside, this time over the **Iterable**, and again `filter` which will return another **Iterable**, but the first `filter` expects a **Boolean**. What exactly did you wanted to do?

Comment: filteredRDD = oldRDD.filter{ case ((key,value)) => value.filter(x => x.next()._1 == "some_string") }

Comment: @firsni Yes! My rdd contains exctly what you said! Also your last comment returned this error: `value next is not a member of (String, String)`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Hello and thank you for your answer. I want to filter my RDD, which has the form I stated in my question based on the 1st element of the second tuple! e.g. "Give me all the rows that have the value "CLASS_A" at the 1st element of the 2nd tuple!"

Comment: @ArisKantas What do you mean with the _"1st element of the 2nd tuple"_ the second element is not a tuple, is a collection fo tuples, as such its first element is also a tuple, a tuple is never equals to `"CLASS_A"` because that is a **String**.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Ok now i get it! Thanks a lot for that and sorry for my missunderstanding. So let's say I have a lot of tuples. How can I access an element on one of them?

Comment: @ArisKantas Many ways... you want the first element of the collection, use `head`. You want the last element, use `last`. You want the third element, use `apply(3)`. Or you want to ensure that for all elements some _predicate_ holds, use `forall`, or maybe you only care if at least one element satisfy the _predicate_ use `exists`. It really depends on what you want to do.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I am going to print this comment and put it on my wall. Many thanks! You gave me the solution to my problem ans also the knowledge I needed.